# fopen() does not work after choosing file from file open dialog in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

In an **MFC** application I have a file browse button. When I click it and select a file, the file is loaded and things are fine.

After this I have a function, which attempts to open another file using `fopen(),` but can not open the file although file is present. If I select cancel in the file browse dialog, `fopen()` works fine but as soon as I select a file using file browse dialog fopen does not work.

Can someone tell why this is happening.

Comment: Can you share the code please. It is hard to debug a question and a lot easier to read code.

Comment: Unrelated, but I'm curious about why are you using `fopen` instead of `fstream`?

Comment: could be something as simple as a permissions issue... check the errno for clues

Comment: I only had to check if file is present or not so i was doing FilePopinter = fopen("filename"); if(FilePopinter ){...}else{...}  but it was not working. I tried using ofstream::good() as Joachim Pileborg said and its working fine i dont know how :|
Anyways Thankyou everyone .

Comment: What is your second argument to `fopen()`?  Because it normally takes 2 of them (one for filename, one for mode)

Comment: second argument was "r".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you specify second file by relative path and after opening first file using dialog, working directory is changed. When you press `Cancel` then working directory is not changed and it works.

Solution to this issue is e.g. to specify this second file using full, non-relative path.

Comment: I tried using non-relative path but it dint work. Instead i used fsteam::good to check if file is present or not and its working fine. I dont know what was wrong with fopen but fstream works fine. Anyways Thanks Psur.